# Using case_when() to upload files based on the values of a variable in R with glue()? Specifically, having trouble with the "else" statement syntax

Tags: r, file, if-statement, dplyr

I wanted to use the case_when() function to upload files into my script based on the values of the variables below.

```
#Variables:
#Acceptable values include "SJ", "SR", & "test"
BP-data <- "test"
#If using "test" data, the next variable would be filled out accordingly. If not using "test" data, it wouldn't matter what the following variable is assigned to.
test-tables <- "SR"
```

From previous questions, I understood the "if-else" statement syntax was:

```
 case_when(rando_var == "something", 
            TRUE ~ "something_else")
```

However, I'm having trouble achieving my desired results with the following code:

```
BU_Table <- case_when(BP-data == "test" ~ 
read.delim(glue("~//R5_SSO//Tables//{test-tables}_BU_Table.txt"),sep="\t",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
TRUE ~ 
read.delim(glue("~//R5_SSO//Tables//{BP-data}_BU_Table.txt"),sep="\t",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '//Tables//test_BU_Table.txt': No such file or directory
```

This happens because the "test_BU_Table.txt" doesn't exist which is why I want to import the `test-tables` BU table instead. I want the code to 'change' the file name according to the values in `BP-data` and `test-tables`. For example, if `BP-data == "test"` *,* I want to import the file *"*SR_BU_Table.txt". If not, I want to import the file "{BP-data}_BU_Table.txt" instead. Right now, it seems my code executes my else statement even if the first condition is satisfied.

I'm also not sure if I can even use case_when() like this. So if there's a different way to achieve this, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

- Randy

Comment: Do not use `case_when` for conditional code exectuion. It would be better to use a standard `if/else `statement. Also I'm not sure how you are running this code because `BP-data <- "test"` is not value R syntax. Variable cannot contain dashes without special escaping. Also the paths you show in the error are missing the "R5_SSO" part. Make sure your example is actually reproducible and valid code.

Comment: I initially used underscores while typing the question, but they were auto converting the text to italics, so I used dashes instead. I also altered the file path in the error message for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a standard if/else statement.

```
BU_Table <- if(`BP-data` == "test") { 
  read.delim(glue("~//R5_SSO//Tables//{test tables}_BU_Table.txt"),sep="\t",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
} else {
  read.delim(glue("~//R5_SSO//Tables//{BP-data}_BU_Table.txt"),sep="\t",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```